# How to match when a property isn't defined in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to enable certain components based on whether a property exists in the application.properties file. My services are:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "disco", name = "url", matchIfMissing = true)
@Component
public class LocalDiscoService {}
```

and

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "disco", name = "url", havingValue = "")
@Component
public class ClusterDiscoService {}
```

I intend on there being a local deployment of my app, and an in-cluster version. The in-cluster version requires the `disco.url` to be defined in the properties file, and it'd be nice if the local deployment can function without ever knowing about `disco.url`. So when working in-cluster I'd like the properties file to be:

```
disco.url=http://discovery.discovery.svc.cluster.local:8761
```

And the local properties file would need nothing. With this configuration, when I don't have the `disco.url` in the properties file, it works out great, and the LocalDiscoService is activated. But when I define the `disco.url` in the properties file, I get errors with both services wanting to be active, but only one is allowed.

I sense the issue here is the `ConditionalOnProperty` for the localDiscoService. I think it matches and enables whether the `disco.url` is defined or not (because of the matchIfMissing).

Is there a way to enable a component when a certain property *isn't* defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "disco", name = "url", havingValue = "false")
@Component
public class LocalDiscoService
```

And the in-cluster one is:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "disco", name = "url", havingValue = "")
@Component
public class ClusterDiscoService
```

When I want to use the in cluster version, I can define the `disco.url` with the actual URL, but if I want to use the LocalDiscoService, I just set `disco.url=` in the properties file. No url needed.